# Browsing each column of a record separately

Tags: plsql

I have a table that has *a lot* of columns. For some reason, I need to fetch data from it and then do some stuff on each column value separately. So I'd like to do something like this :

```
SELECT record FROM table
FOREACH field of the record
    do some stuff
```

The "do some stuff" part shall do something according to the column name.

Is there an easy way to perform such a browse in PL/SQL ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't loop like this through fields of a record. However, you could use DBMS_SQL to loop through all the returned columns and do whatever you need. Check my simple example below based on this thread: [Loop through columns of a record with DBMS_SQL](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1004502)

```
CREATE TABLE my_iter_tab_test (
  id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  salary NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO my_iter_tab_test VALUES (1, 'Smith', 5000);
INSERT INTO my_iter_tab_test VALUES (2, 'Brown', 6000);

COMMIT;

DECLARE
  v_cur NUMBER;
  v_temp NUMBER;
  v_col_cnt NUMBER;
  v_desc_tab_rec DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  v_ret NUMBER;
  v_v_val VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_cur, 'SELECT * FROM my_iter_tab_test', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

  v_temp := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(v_cur);

  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(v_cur, v_col_cnt, v_desc_tab_rec);

  FOR v_i IN 1..v_col_cnt
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_desc_tab_rec(v_i).col_name);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_cur ,v_i, v_v_val, 2000);
  END LOOP;

  LOOP
    v_ret := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(v_cur);
    EXIT WHEN v_ret = 0;

    FOR v_i IN 1..v_col_cnt
    LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_cur, v_i, v_v_val);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_desc_tab_rec(v_i).col_name || ' : ' || v_v_val);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_cur);
END;
```

Output:

```
ID
NAME
SALARY
ID : 1
NAME : Smith
SALARY : 5000
ID : 2
NAME : Brown
SALARY : 6000
```

I guess you'll want to change the `DEFINE_COLUMN` to proper types in your final solution.